# I want my website users to receive payments from other users on the website?

Tags: php, curl, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a website that offers members to sell ad space to other members in the website. I want the ad space seller to receive a payment via PayPal from the ad space buyer. Can that be done using PayPal IPN and PHP cURL?

How can I verify that the seller received money from the buyer so I can make changes to the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PayPal IPN feature.

You can refer to below link for IPN integration .
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

And also you can get the IPN sample code:
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples
PayPal will send payment transaction detail information to your server, then your server can process the data and store it into database.